# Is there an Algorithm to index a collection on permutation of properties?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, indexing

Given:

```
IMatchCriteria {
    string PropA{get;}
    string PropB{get;}
    int? PropC {get;}
    int? PropD {get;}
}

IReportRecord : IMatchCriteria {...}

IMatchCriteriaSet : IMatchCriteria {
    int MatchId {get;}
    double Limit{get;}
}

public class Worker{

private List<IMatchCriteriaSet> _matchers = GetIt();
//Expecting this list to be huge, ***upto 0.1m***. Some of the sample matchers:
// MatchId=1, Limit=1000, PropA=A, PropC=101, PropD=201
// MatchId=2, Limit=10,   PropA=A
// MatchId=3, Limit=20,            PropC=101
// MatchId=4, Limit=500,                      PropD=201

   //Based on sample entries:
   //Input: reportRecord{ PropA=A, PropC=101 }, Ouput: 1000, 20
   //Input: reportRecord{ PropA=A1, PropC=102, PropD=201 }, Ouput: 500
    public IEnumerable<double> GetMatchingLimits(IReportRecord reportRecord) {
         //Bad, very bad option:
         foreach(var matcher in _matchers){
             var matchFound=true;
             if(reportRecord.PropA!=null && reportRecord.PropA!=matcher.PropA){                
                 continue;
             }
             if(reportRecord.PropB!=null && reportRecord.PropA!=matcher.PropB){
                 continue;
             }
             if(reportRecord.PropC!=null && reportRecord.PropC.Value!=matcher.PropC.Value){
                 continue;
             }
             if(reportRecord.PropD!=null && reportRecord.PropD.Value!=matcher.PropD.Value){
                 continue;
             }
             yield return matcher.Limit;
         }
    }

    }
```

Note: Expecting IMatchCriteriaSet to be 0.1m records.
Expecting GetMatchingLimits to be called 1m times.
The requirement is to do all this for a real-time application.

Essentially what I need is a way to index list of IMatchCriteria. But can not use Dictionary because my key is not defined.
Looking for some algorithm to tackle this problem ***efficiently***.

Any suggested solution in scope of .net (not just c#) would be useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one dictionary for each indexable property, mapping to a set of matchers. Then you can do a dictionary lookup for every property that is set in your record (logarithmic complexity), and intersect the resulting sets. Start with the smallest result set and whittle it down to get the best run time.

Comment: I just worked out to the same solution. The downside is restricting the property matchers (a new property would call for a new dict, and code change).

Comment: Realized one more gap. Even if I create one dict for each property, I wont be able to use any map for reducing the set! Because, for each propery I need to consider two sets: 1) a map of properyValue and matchers in scope, 2) where that property is not specified.
In the suggested solution we will miss out 2) if we start with a properyMatcherDict and reduce the set.

Comment: "Not specified" can be treated easily as a special value (`null`). As for code change, yes that's an issue but adding a property is a code change as well. To localize the impact, factor out the methods which need to enumerate properties and place them close to the interface declaration. If you have many such interfaces, consider code generation (compile-time or run-time via dynamic methods).